# Calling instance function on each object in array

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I have an array of objects that contain instance methods. I can iterate over each object and call it specifically like this:

```
items.forEach(function(i) { i.show(false) });
```

But I was hoping for a less verbose version like the following, which does not work.

```
items.forEach.show(false);
```

or even

```
items.show(false);
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: `items.forEach((i) => i.show(false));`

Comment: Thanks, but that is not as clean as I would prefer. It is much easier to read when there is less brackets involved. Is that the best I can get?

Comment: Yes... that is using [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: If you want less brackets you should consider using another language than js ^^

Comment: Ha! I wish :) I come from a C++ background so I long for something better... :)

Comment: You could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/w99atyu6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The shortest way is using [ES 6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
items.forEach(i => i.show(false));
```

2) Use a helper function:

```
function iterator(i) { 
  i.show(false) 
}

items.forEach(iterator);
```

3) Define a generator:

```
function gen() {
   var funcName = arguments[0],
     params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
   return function(item) {
      item[funcName].apply(item, params);
   };
}

items.forEach(gen('show', false));     // -> i.show(false);
items.forEach(gen('show', true));      // -> i.show(true);
items.forEach(gen('delete', 1, true)); // -> i.delete(1, true);
```

Comment: Is there a helper function to make it as clean as I want? I failed to think of one.

Comment: Check the option 2

Comment: Since I want to be able to call any function something like that wouldn't do. I want to avoid having to type out each function and have an iterator for it. Which means the helper needs to support whatever function name I pass, and the variable argument list that a function may have.

Comment: The `forEach` requires a function to iterate. One way or another you need to define a function.

Comment: I don't have to use "forEach" if there is a cleaner method. I just want to call a function in each object.

Comment: @RylerSturden how about: `for (var i in items) items[i].show(false);`?

Comment: @LPK the `i` variable is the key, and `items` is the array / object being iterated over, using `i.show(false);` would result in a `TypeError` as the method `show()` is not defined on a string/int

Comment: Ah I wish there was some way to clean this answer up with a #define or something but it will have to do. Thanks Dmitri.

Comment: @RylerSturden No problem. What about the option 3?

Comment: It's a lot uglier than option 1. :)

Comment: @RylerSturden :D At least we tried all the options. Thanks for the nice question.

Comment: Yeah we tried a lot, I tried a lot too. It is funny that I keep thinking I will find the RIGHT option soon!!! But your option 1 is fairly good. Just wish I could make it a bit sexier.